# How do I have a bot that can have timer instructions?

Tags: discord.py

I want to make a bot that has a timer command, like `!timing 00:00:00`

then the bot says `@user The alarm time you set is up!`

how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will let you type ***!timings 10***

**NOTE** the time is in seconds

Creating the bot

```py
import discord
import time
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')  # Setting the command prefix

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

     
client.run('INSERT BOT TOKEN HERE')
```

Next with the bot you created lest create the command
Command:

```py
@client.command(help=('Set a timer or reminder'))
async def timings(ctx, *, wait:int):
    user = ctx.author  # Getting the user

    if wait:  # If a number is given
        time.sleep(wait)  # Waiting the number of seconds given
        await ctx.send(f'Hey {user.mention} your timer is going off')
        return
```

Add the command below the @Client.event

Comment: Note inside the command code you can type before the time.sleep(wait) ctx.send('Remimder set!')

Comment: If you use `time.sleep`, the whole bot won't when it's "sleeping", ([reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#what-does-blocking-mean)), use `await asyncio.sleep(n)` instead.

Comment: actually, I just want to know how the timer command is coded.